# Send an email with dataframe as a flextable

Tags: html, r, flextable

I have a code which I use to send mails everyday and I use the xtable package to get it done.
But lately, I've got accustomed to using the flex table as it is more feasible to my requirements.

But when I change the code to use the flextable function, all I am sending is a blank mail with no body at all.

This is the sample data set

```
 samplemondata<-structure(list(Root.Cause = c("Blocking", "Created in Error", 
"Duplicate", "Horizontal liquid bottle", "Overhanging", "Title Not Facing Out", 
"Trash in the Bin", "Units Not Stowed Securely", "Unorganized", 
"Wrong Bin Type"), BCN1 = c("109", "", "", "", "", "70", "", 
"7", "1", "6"), FCO1 = c("98", "1", "", "1", "", "31", "4", "4", 
 "", "4"), FRA7 = c("401", "", "", "", "2", "260", "", "2", "", 
"100"), HAM2 = c("414", "", "", "", "1", "115", "", "1", "1", 
"44"), LCY2 = c("230", "", "", "1", "1", "102", "", "3", "", 
"15"), LTN4 = c("30", "", "", "", "", "7", "", "", "", ""), MAN1 = c("66", 
"", "", "", "1", "22", "3", "1", "", "3"), MAN2 = c("104", "", 
"", "", "", "50", "", "2", "", "12"), MAN3 = c("92", "", "", 
"1", "", "36", "", "1", "", "5"), SZZ1 = c("344", "", "", "", 
"2", "114", "1", "15", "", "10")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Please find the code below.

```
  library(sendmailR)
  library(dplyr)
  library(flextable)



msgJP <- try(mime_part(paste('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
                           Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
                           <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                           <head>
                           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
                           <title>HTML demo</title>
                           <style type="text/css">
                           </style>
                           </head>  
                           <body>',"hello,<br>","check out the data for self audit.","<br>",print(flextable(samplemon),include.rownames = FALSE, type = 'html'),'</body>
                           </html>')))


msgJP[["headers"]][["Content-Type"]] <- "text/html"

body    <- list(msgJP)

from <- "abc@xyz.com"
to<-c("abc@xyz.com")
subject <- paste0("Why is this not working?")
sendmail(from, to, subject, body, control = list(smtpServer="smtp.amazon.com"))
```

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because print method is displaying the flextable, it does not return the HTML value. The method `format(fletable_obj, type = "HTML")` return the HTML value.

You should modify the HTML creation as:

```
msgJP <- try(mime_part(paste('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>HTML demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>  
<body>',"hello,<br>","check out the data for self audit.","<br>",
format(flextable(samplemondata), type = "html"),
'</body>
</html>')))
```

Comment: note a minor fix has been made (on github for now) to make sure borders are collapsing

Comment: Thanks for the response. The code works fine but only until I have made some customisations. I have updated the question with my customizations and I am stuck with this error. Error in flextable(ft) : is.data.frame(data) is not TRUE

Comment: You made a mistake. you are calling flextable with an argument ft - ft is already a flextable. By changing your question, you are making things hard to understand for future readers.